# Wrong serial number for ASUS ZenBook UX306UA?

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, serial-number

I bought myself an ASUS ZenBook UX306UA. On the bottom it says UX306U Notebook PC. But, under About in settings it says that my computer is a UX305UAB Signature Edition, and when I registered it with it's serial number on the ASUS website it said that my computer was a UX305UA. Are these all the same products, or something else?

Comment: Yes, they are the same model number

Comment: @Ramhound Really? UX305UA and UX306UA seem to be different computers: https://www.ultrabookreview.com/11496-asus-zenbook-ux306ua-reviewed/ "Asus will upgrade their popular Zenbook UX305 series in the second half of 2016, and the updated model is rebranded as the Zenbook UX306 series."

Comment: ASUS changes the modem depending on the region it's sold it.  At the end of the day, it's the exact same device, and there is no difference between the two devices.